# Brownie runs just one test instead of two

Tags: brownie

I have two functions in my test file; `test_simple_storage.py`, but when I run `brownie test` only the first one runs. I tried to elect just the second function to be tested and it simply returned `1 deselected`

Comment: Can you show the code for the tests?

Comment: Also, try using the backtick key ` instead of the quote